# How to delay an action (or) How to control program flow to wait for a particular action to complete

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite

I have code something like this.

I have to move a sprite to particular position and after completion of that action, i want to remove it.

But it is removing it without performing the action. How, to achieve this.

sp is a Sprite

```
sp->runAction(MoveTo::create(1.0, Vec2(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2)));
this->removeChild(sp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto move = MoveTo::create(1.0, Vec2(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2));
auto moveDone = CallFuncN( CC_CALLBACk_1(ClassName::removeSprite, this) );
sp->runAction( Sequence::create( move, moveDone, NULL ) );

//create a function removeSprite, it will be called after action move is finished
void ClassName::removeSprite(Node* pNode) {

pNode->removeFromParent();
}
```

Comment: Instead i think i can remove the specific child from this directly

Comment: You should add more information to your answer, regarding how/why this code works. Code without explanation isn't much useful.